# how to detect accelerometer changes with python

Tags: python, accelerometer

I have an accelerometer that I would like to use to detect the movement of my baby at night, has anyone attempted to write code to achieve something similar, any pointers.

bear in mind that the sensor can be positioned in any position and the code will determine the location it at and the movement accordingly.

the sensor has a little noise and this should be filtered out.

here is the code i am using to get values from the sensor and also below typical reading

```
import adxl345
import time, sys

accel = adxl345.ADXL345()
accel.setRange(adxl345.RANGE_2G)

while True:
    axes = accel.getAxes(True)

    x = axes['x']
    y = axes['y']
    z = axes['z']

    print x
    print y
    print z
    time.sleep(2)
```

Typical Readings:

1.028
-0.264
-0.12

1.032
-0.264
-0.104

1.036
-0.264
-0.1

1.028
-0.26
-0.116

1.04
-0.26
-0.108

1.044
-0.264
-0.112

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your accelerometter, so I don't know how it works, but I would say that when you put the accelerometer on your baby, set some variables to the initial value, and then calculate every time the difference between the initial values and the new values. Set a treshold value ( because your baby isn't a stone and it will move a little randomly ) and fire an alert if the values change too much.

Also, if you use only the axis of the accelerometer you will know the orientation of you baby, but if you want to know the real position you need to integrate the acceleration to obtain the position ( second order ODE ).

Sorry for answering, but I don't have enough rep to comment.